# stats - limiting distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $0 < p < 1$, and let $X_{n}$ have p.d.f. $f_{n}(x) = ( 1 – p ) ( n + 1 ) ( 1 – x )^{n} + p n x^{n – 1}$, for 0 < x < 1, zero elsewhere. Find the limiting distribution of $X_{n}$.

Course textbook is Introduction to Mathematical Statistics, Seventh Edition, by Robert V. Hogg, Joseph W. McKean, Allen T. Craig., this is from ch. 5.2.

So do I simply take the limit of $F_{n}(x)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, and name that distribution? ie $F(x) = \int_{0}^{1} (1-p) (n+1) (1-x)^n+p n x^{n-1} dx = p - p + 1$? That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

The limiting distribution is discrete with mass 1-p at 0 and p at 1. To show this pass to the limit in the sequence of c.d.f.'s

$F_n(x)=0, x \le 0; =(1-p)-(1-p)(1-x)^{n+1}+px^n, x \ge 0$

Comment: Why is it discrete? Isn't x allowed to be anything between 0 and 1?

Comment: For $x \le 0$ $F_n(x)=0 \to 0$

Comment: For $x \in (0,1)$ $(1-x) \in (0,1)$ then $(1-x)^n \to 0$ and $x^n \to 0$ therefore for such $x \in (0,1)$ $F_n(x) \to 1-p$, For $x \ge 1, F_n(x)=1-p+p=1 \to 1,$ so the limiting distribution function has two poins of increas 0, and 1.

Comment: I think I understand. Is it alright to say $(1-p)(1-x)^{n+1} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ if $0<x<1$ and $px^{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ if $0<x<1$?

Comment: yes, that is what I am saying

Answer (score 0):

$\int f = 1$ by definition. You want to show what $f_n$ or $F_n$ look like, then take the limit to get $f^*$ or $F^*$ and see if you recognize the distribution.